# Maven site documentation: Add links to additional documents

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin, parent-pom

I want to generate project documentations with the Maven site plugin. The default layout, structure and functions with "Project Information" and "Project Reports" is ok for me. 
But I want to add an additional (third) section "Additional Documentation", which links to some more documents, if there are such documents in the project.

I can create a directory  `src/site/resources/otherDocu` and the documents will be copied to the  `target/site/otherDocu`  directory, as desired. However, the generated site does not link to them.

I would like a third section "Additional Documentation", which lists and links the files in the mentioned directory. I want to do this with as small an overhead as possible. Specifically, if it can be avoided, I do not want to include an own `site.xml`, along with css etc. as described in many solutions. How can I use the default site configuration and only "inject" a part? Or, if this is the only way, it should be possible to configure a file (say `site.xml`) only once in a parent POM and inherit it for all other projects. How can I make it list the files found in `src/site/resources/otherDocu` and display links to them?

Or, what I also was thinking of: I could write an own report plugin, which does this, and then I only need to specify this plugin in the "reporting / plugins" section in the POM, as I did for the other reporting plugins. With this solution, I could probably create an additional entry in the "Project Reports" section, like for every other reporting plugin, which is a step in the correct direction. But I need several entries (because of several linked documents), or one entry "Additional docu" with sub-entries.

Which way is the easier to go? Does you have a recommendation or a similar solution? Does anyone have a file (`site.xml` or similar) which already does some listing, does not need all other resources (images etc.) and can be inherited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to keep the default behaviour is to use [something in your site descriptor:](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/doxia-sitetools/doxia-decoration-model/decoration.html#class_menu)

```xml
  <body>
     <menu ref="reports"/>
     <menu ref="modules"/>
  </body>
```

The thing you are using to automatically copying the files to the target is suposed for [resources as you can read in the docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html#Adding_Extra_Resources).

Furthermore to automatically created documents you need to go the way via a report plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I followed your suggestions and it turned out that by writing my own reporting plugin, I do not even need an own site descriptor, but can use the default one (no need for my own site.xml). The output of my report is added to the standard list of reports (the one that would be generated by `<menu ref="reports"/>`).

Comment: Btw, links I found most useful for this: 
[Codehaus: write report plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Write+your+own+report+plugin), [Sonatype: write plugin](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html).
[4thline.org: about outputDirectory etc](http://4thline.org/articles/Howto%20write%20a%20Maven%20report%20plugin.html), 
[maven: Plugin configuration](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html), 
[maven: Java5 Annotations](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I have done .. relatively straightforward:

src/site/site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project name="${project.name}">
    <body>
        <menu name="Menu Title">
            <item name="Documentation" href="docs.html"/>
        </menu>
    </body>
</project>
```

Above creates a link to docs.html page. Then create the docs page using apt (or other languages possible)

src/site/apt/docs.apt:

```
    -------------
    Documentation
    -------------

Documentation

    Some text {{{/path/to/doc}document}}.
```

If you don't want to create a separate page, you can probably just insert links to the documents in the site.xml.

Comment: Thanks, but does not what I want for 2 reasons: First, having own site.xml deletes all the default behaviour (links to project information and project reports), which I would have to reconstruct/include "by hand" into my own site.xml (unless this could be done by some very short code - can it?). Second, the solution should collect files in the directory "otherDocumentation" without me having to list them one by one. I would like a common solution for all projects, the same documentation configuration file(s) which automatically collect existing project documentation which can vary per project.

Comment: _First, having own site.xml deletes all the default behaviour ..._ -- The example I showed simply adds a menu section to the default site page, it does not replace the entire page. _Second, the solution should collect files in the directory "otherDocumentation" without me having to list them one by one._ -- In my own project, I generate dynamic content using xhtml and javascript. Although this may not suit your needs, it does demonstrate that dynamic content is possible.

Comment: _The example I showed simply adds a menu section to the default site page, it does not replace the entire page._ -- Wish it were like that... Of course, the default page layout and CSS etc. is still there, if you mean that. But when I use the site.xml you listed, all other menu entries are gone and the one defined in the site.xml is the only one left. I could use `<menu ref="reports"/><menu ref="modules"/>` to add the default menu entries again, but would like to avoid that. Found a solution that suited me more, by writing an own report plugin, as suggested by @khmarbaise.